# Are there good public datasets for ocean currents?

Tags: ocean-currents, open-data, reanalysis

Some years ago I made a weather app based on a yearly updated Copernicus dataset.
Its main features are monthly wind roses that summarize the last 5 years for a selected area.
My idea was that this would be a nice tool for holiday or passage planning.
This [ERA5 hourly data on single levels](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=overview) dataset from [cds.climate.copernicus.eu](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/) is used.

What I am currently missing are the ocean currents. I saw that the dataset includes Stokes drift but unfortunately this is much lower than the ocean currents. Is there any related dataset that includes such currents? Or another dataset with a similar resolution?

Currently, I am using 8 measurements per day of the previous 5 years minus 20° from the poles (70°S to 70°N).

Comment: Try something like: https://charts.ecmwf.int/catalogue/packages/oras5/products/oras5_xymaps_1m?AnomalyMode=Full%20field&Field=Surface%20Meridional%20Velocity&base_time=202312010000

Comment: Also: https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/soda-simple-ocean-data-assimilation

Comment: Ah, "zonal" and "meridional" velocity. That's what I need to look for. Thanks

Comment: [HYCOM](https://www.hycom.org) is also widely used in offshore engineering for operational planning.

Comment: Maybe a followup question: Is "rotated zonal" velocity the value I am looking for? In the dataset documentation "rotated zonal" is described as "Eastward horizontal surface velocity of a water parcel", whereas "zonal" as "Horizontal velocity of a water parcel in the direction of x axis of the ocean model". So, I have to assume the x-direction of the ocean model is not necessarily eastward?